# Object is unknown type - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This code is a direct copy from  the React Material UI site

```
    <Select
                  id="selectedSubusecases"
                  multiple
                  value={stepsState.campaignOverviewStep.selectedSubUsecases}
                  onChange={handleChangeMultiple}
                  input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
                  renderValue={selected => (
                    <div className={classes.chips}>
                      {selected.map(value => (
                        <Chip
                          key={value}
                          label={value}
                          className={classes.chip}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  MenuProps={SubusecaseMenuProps}
                >
```

But when I try to use it I get "Object is of type unknown" for "selected"
`{selected.map(value => (`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

````
                    <div className={classes.chips}>
                      {(selected as string[]).map(value => (
                        <Chip
                          key={value}
                          label={value}
                          className={classes.chip}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}```
````